# Laravel - how to update my value in variable and put into session laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, session, foreach

I have variable getscore in my controller function ?

```
 public   function questionquiz5(Request $request){


           static $getscore=0;

     $getidvalue = Input::get('getid');
     $getanswervalue = Input::get('getanswer');

     $dbscore = \DB::table('5question')->select('question_id','correct_answer','question_marks')->
     where('question_id','=',$getidvalue)->get();

   foreach ($dbscore as $value) {

       if ( $getanswervalue==($value->correct_answer) ){

                       $this->getscore  =  $this->getscore + $value->question_marks;           

          }elseif($getanswervalue == null){

                       $emptyvalue = -1;
                       $this->getscore += $emptyvalue;

          }else{

                       $novalue=0;
                       $this->getscore += $novalue;               
          }

    }
          echo "$this->getscore";


       Session::push('getscoresession',$this->getscore);


    $getsession = [  'qid' => $getidvalue,  'answer' => $getanswervalue];

       Session::push('answer', $getsession);

    return response()->json(['qid'=>$getidvalue,'answer'=>$getanswervalue]);
```

}

i want to increase my value of getscore my applying foreach loop but not working ....as it always resets to zero i think?
how to make it happen so when i run loop so my getscore value added and stored in session ?

Comment: `public   function questionquiz5(Request $request){static $getscore=0;` =>`$getscore=0; public   function questionquiz5(Request $request){`

Answer (score 0):

Putting variables to session

```
session('name', 'value');
```

Or

```
$request->session()->('name', 'value');
```

Retrieve session

```
session('name');
```

Add to variable in foreach loop

```
$name = session('name');

foreach($things as $thing){
    $name += $thing
}
```

Update session value AFTER foreach

```
$request->session()->put('name', 'value')
```

Or

```
session('name', 'value');
```